# Kentico - Excluding a specific Custom Table from staging data tasks

Tags: kentico

I am adding a new custom table to my Kentico 10 website.  I want any custom table structural changes synched, however I do not want data synched between my different environments.

I do have other custom tables though that I want to keep logging staging tasks for.

How do I exclude for a specific custom table?  I can see sample:
https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/excluding-content-from-staging-and-integration

But I don't know what property I can use on the synchronizedObject to validate if its relevant to the custom table.

All the samples I've found so far have been for users/roles which are an out of the box object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a global handler for the log change events of custom table in question.  Use something like this:

```
using CMS;
using CMS.DataEngine;

// Registers the custom module into the system
[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(CustomHandlerModule))]

public class CustomHandlerModule : Module
{
    // Module class constructor, the system registers the module under the name "LogChangeHandlers"
    public CustomHandlerModule()
        : base("CustomHandlerModule") { }

    // Contains initialization code that is executed when the application starts
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit();
        ObjectEvents.LogChange.Before += LogChange_Before;
    }

    private void LogChange_Before(object sender, LogObjectChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // check the type info for your specific custom table type/item.  
        // Could use a switch statement here too if you have multiple
        // make sure to update "namespace" and "classname" with your custom data.  
        // Do not modify the "customtableitem" string, that is needed.
        if (e.Settings.InfoObj.TypeInfo.ObjectType.ToLower() == "customtableitem.namespace.classname")
        {
            e.Settings.LogStaging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed.  I notice we currently have a global handler for StagingEvents.LogTask.Before - do you know how that differs to LogChange?

Comment: The `LogChange` event fires when object tasks are logged. You can disable tasks logging for staging, integration etc.  `StagingEvents` event fires on the source server when the staging logs the task.  So that being said, the LogChange event fires before the StagingEvents fire meaning one less event that fires if you perform you check in the LogChange event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post very helpful, https://www.bluemodus.com/blog/october-2016/kentico-tip-how-to-create-a-staging-filter-module